# Package conflicts while installing Pandas using Conda in python 3.11

Tags: python-3.x, conda

I have following list of packages in my Current environment;

```
(linprogenv)  jayantsingh@jayants-MacBook-Pro  ~/Documents/pynb files  $  conda list
# packages in environment at /Users/jayantsingh/opt/miniconda3/envs/linprogenv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
bzip2                     1.0.8                h0d85af4_4    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2023.7.22            h8857fd0_0    conda-forge
libexpat                  2.5.0                hf0c8a7f_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h0d85af4_5    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.42.0               h58db7d2_0    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               h8a1eda9_5    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.4                  hf0c8a7f_0    conda-forge
openssl                   3.1.1                h8a1eda9_1    conda-forge
pip                       23.2.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python                    3.11.4          h30d4d87_0_cpython    conda-forge
readline                  8.2                  h9e318b2_1    conda-forge
setuptools                68.0.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.12               h5dbffcc_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2023c                h71feb2d_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.41.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h775f41a_0    conda-forge
```

Next I am trying to install pandas using following command,

```
(linprogenv)  jayantsingh@jayants-MacBook-Pro  ~/Documents/pynb files  $  conda install -c anaconda pandas
```

I am getting lots of package conflicts, but am showing few of them here.

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: - 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package libexpat conflicts for:
wheel -> python -> libexpat[version='>=2.5.0,<3.0a0']
python=3.11 -> libexpat[version='>=2.5.0,<3.0a0']
pandas -> pypy3.9[version='>=7.3.11'] -> libexpat[version='>=2.5.0,<3.0a0']
libexpat
pip -> python[version='>=3.7'] -> libexpat[version='>=2.5.0,<3.0a0']
setuptools -> python[version='>=3.7'] -> libexpat[version='>=2.5.0,<3.0a0']

Package six conflicts for:
wheel -> packaging[version='>=20.2'] -> six
pandas -> python-dateutil[version='>=2.8.1'] -> six[version='>=1.5']
```

For reference here is the output of Conda info

```
(linprogenv)  jayantsingh@jayants-MacBook-Pro  ~/Documents/pynb files  $  conda info

     active environment : linprogenv
    active env location : /Users/jayantsingh/opt/miniconda3/envs/linprogenv
            shell level : 2
       user config file : /Users/jayantsingh/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/jayantsingh/.condarc
          conda version : 4.12.0
    conda-build version : 3.21.8
         python version : 3.8.13.final.0
       virtual packages : __osx=10.16=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /Users/jayantsingh/opt/miniconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /Users/jayantsingh/opt/miniconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/jayantsingh/opt/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/jayantsingh/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/jayantsingh/opt/miniconda3/envs
                          /Users/jayantsingh/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.12.0 requests/2.27.1 CPython/3.8.13 Darwin/22.5.0 OSX/10.16
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

And there is strict channel priority setting to keep everything ordered.

```
(linprogenv)  jayantsingh@jayants-MacBook-Pro  ~/Documents/pynb files  $  conda config --show channel_priority
channel_priority: strict
```

Can I please get some help in fixing this installation issues. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Could you please add the output of `conda env export --from-history -n linprogenv`? That will tell us what actual constraints you've put on the environment. BTW, Mamba v1.4+ has infinitely better conflict reporting. (`conda install -n base -c conda-forge mamba`, then use `mamba` instead of `conda`)

Comment: Works fine for me with Mamba: `mamba create -n foo -c conda-forge python=3.11 pandas`. I made a lockfile on prefix.dev, which you can install with: `micromamba create -f https://prefix.dev/envs/mfansler/pandas-py311/f64ggc8rvgqb/conda-lock.yml -n pandas-py311`

Comment: @merv appreciate the response. does it mean that `conda` is defunct now as a package ,manager. And everything regarding installing packages shd move to `mamba`.

Comment: No, I wouldn't say that. The `conda` tool also solves fine for me. The Conda team has been playing catch-up with `mamba`, but is still actively developed and improved on. More to the problem though, please include the output I suggested - that is essential to debugging your issue.